# MS Access won't update table after execution of INSERT INTO query through ucanaccess in java

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I have java program to assign vacationers to hotel rooms.
Whenever I try to insert a record of a hotel room to ms access table using INSERT INTO query through ucanaccess in java, the relavant table won't update unless I close and re-open access, or when I hit the 'compact and repair' command. Is there any way to fix this and make access immediately update the table with the new record without having to take these steps?
There is a part of my java source code:

```
public boolean addHotelRoom(Integer roomNum, Integer periodNum,
        boolean hasDisabledDevices)
{

    try
    {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Consts.CONN_STR);
                CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(Consts.SQL_INS_HOTEL_ROOM))
        {

            stmt.setInt(1, roomNum);
            stmt.setInt(2, periodNum);
            stmt.setBoolean(3, hasDisabledDevices);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            return true;

        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Check the return result of `stmt.executeUpdate()` to make sure that it did actually affect the table and `conn.commit()` in case auto commit is off

Comment: @MadProgrammer For some reason it helped the first time, and then it didn't

Comment: Well, there's not much more that could be done, as I don't know the requirements of your database. Maybe there's a constraint which prevents duplicates, it's near impossible to diagnose with the available information.  The best you can do is ensure that `stmt.executeUpdate` is returning a non-zero value and that you're committing the change if auto commit is disabled

Comment: What options are set in CONN_STR?

Answer (score 2):

UCanAccess doesn't support Shared Mode on Access databases.

That's explained [here](http://ucanaccess.blogspot.com/2017/07/multiuser-concurrent-write-access.html) on the UCanAccess blog.

That means, your current use case, having Access open while an UCanAccess application writes to it, is unsupported. Unless support is added in the future, it won't work. There's no current workaround.

A half-workaround might be using a separate front-end and back-end database. Then, you just have to close all tables to close the database, thus avoiding the need to close the entire database. Depending on your exact requirements, you can also have forms in an Access database that work disconnected from the backend, and only connect to fetch or update data.

Note that having UCanAccess write to the database while it's open in Access might cause conflicts/corruption if Access performs writes too. I strongly recommend avoiding it.